# ui router - abstract state inside à normal one (3 levels)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, abstract

i'm trying to get work this combination of sub levels routes.

http://plnkr.co/edit/1nBzppJkB45Ljv5SRW4b?p=preview

i took a sample from ui-route on github and added a parent view (contactg).

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('contactg', {
        url: '/contactg',
        templateUrl: 'contactG.html',
        onEnter: function () { console.log("enter contactG"); }
    })

  .state('contactg.contacts', {
      abstract: true,
      url: '/contacts',
      templateUrl: 'contacts.html',
      controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.contacts = [{ id: 0, name: "Alice" }, { id: 1, name: "Bob" }];
      },
      onEnter: function () {
          console.log("enter contacts");
      }

  })
  .state('contactg.contacts.list', {
      url: '/list',
      // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
      templateUrl: 'contacts.list.html',
      onEnter: function () {
          console.log("enter contacts.list");
      }
  })
  .state('contactg.contacts.detail', {
      url: '/:id',
      // loaded into ui-view of parent's template
      templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
      controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) {
          $scope.person = $scope.contacts[$stateParams.id];
      },
      onEnter: function () {
          console.log("enter contacts.detail");
      }
  })
```

My issues is when i click on an item in contactg.contacts.list, the link generated tends to redirect me to /contacts/:id (detail) instead of /contactg/contacts/:id

is there a way to specify that ?

Thanks
Guillaume.

Comment: can you show, you html code ?

Comment: sure, it is in the plunker link
http://plnkr.co/edit/1nBzppJkB45Ljv5SRW4b?p=preview